# Did John Grisham base The Scandal on a specific incident?

Tags: john-grisham, theodore-boone

In *The Scandal* by John Grisham, Theodore Boone finds out that cheating occurred in the administration of annual standardized tests. It is common knowledge that such cheating scandals occur on a fairly regular basis. Is it known whether John Grisham based his cheating scandal in *The Scandal* on a specific cheating scandal?